# Looking for code to implement this simple asynchronous example

Tags: asynchronous

I'm looking for a simple example of asynchronous code ( preferable in VB with .NET ) to do something like this:

```
Main()
 async Sub1()
 async Sub2()
 await Sub1()
 print "end"
End

Sub1()
 for n=1 to 1000
  { do something }
 next
End sub

Sub2()
 if n=500 in Sub1() then print "Hello"
End sub
```

An alternative could be:

```
Main()
 async Sub1()
 async Sub2()
 await Sub1()
 print "end"
End

Sub1()
 for n=1 to 1000
  if n=500 send signal
  { do something }
 next
End Sub

Sub2()
 if signal is received print "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: This example is all synchronous, not asynchronous. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I do not know the correct term, parallel, maybe. I want to launch 2 routines at the same time, in parallel. While routine Sub1 is running, routine Sub2 is also running and looking the variable N in routine Sub1.

Comment: This makes very little sense - if `Sub2()` is supposed to be triggered by a "signal", why do you call it from `Main`? Why not just call it from `Sub1()`? It's hard to see the idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Right. Sorry to include the alternative "code". It is not what I'm looking for. The alternative code can be based on events (WithEvents, RaiseEvents). I'm looking for ways to launch 2 routines simultaneously.

Comment: @MarcioAB: I think it's this part that doesn't really make sense to us: `if n=500 in Sub1()`

Comment: The code below is not parallel. When I click:<br/>
    - Button1: TextBox1 starts to count.<br/>
    - Button2: TextBox1 still continue to count and nothing in TextBox2.<br/>
- Button2 (again): TextBox1 stops to count and TextBox2 starts to count.<br/>
- Button1: nothing happen in TextBox1 and TextBox2 continue to count<br/>
- Button1 (again): TextBox1 starts to count from 1 and TextBox2 stops to count.<br/>

What I'm looking for is when I click:<br/>
- Button1: TextBox1 starts to count.<br/>
- Button2: TextBox1 continue to count and TextBox2 starts to count.<br/>

Comment: Understood. Let me re-structure the need.

Comment: Let me open a new question about the same need. I think I screw up this.